# How to enable OS X screen sharing (VNC) through SSH?

Tags: macos, ssh, remote-desktop

I forgot to turn on "VNC viewers may control screen with password",
to enter on my working Mac,
is there way to turn-on this feature remotely via SSH (I'm on WindowsXP now)?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Source: <del>`http://technotes.twosmallcoins.com/?p=279`</del> ([archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20150322004508/http://technotes.twosmallcoins.com/?p=279))

Putty is a good SSH client for Windows.

1. SSH into your remote OS X machine with an administrator’s log in and password.
2. Enable Remote Desktop (a.k.a. Screen Sharing, a.k.a. VNC) with this command:

   ```bsh
   sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart \
   -activate -configure -access -on \
   -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes \
   -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw mypasswd \
   -restart -agent -privs -all
   ```
3. Login using a VNC client. As I mentioned, TightVNC worked for me;
   for some reason, RealVNC and UltraVNC didn’t.  Your password is
   “mypasswd” (see the -vncpw flag in the above command;  you can *and
   should* change this).
4. When you are done, turn off screen-sharing using your SSH session:

   ```bsh
   sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart \
   -deactivate -configure -access -off
   ```

Comment: Amazing! Works!

Comment: One thing that Mac RD quite unusable for me (very slowly)... as opossed to windows RDC, which is pretty good.

Comment: Have you tried Vine Server?

Comment: I've never worked with VNC before. Only with SSH once to let my desktop start downloading a file upstairs in my room so that my laptop didn't have to keep running in the living room :p

Comment: 3+ years later and works perfectly in Yosemite. Thanks!

Comment: What if I I'm on mac and want to enable screen sharing with linux? (so no putty there). What can I do?

Comment: Warning: this breaks with the "Remote Desktop Client Update v3.8.5" update. See here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7501620?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: ... and the fix is here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/30088844#30088844 - download older RemoteManagement folder and replace the current, broken one with it. Direct link: http://rmscomputersystems.com/~pscordam/RemoteManagement(ARDAgent3.8.4).zip

Comment: @Novellizator Both Mac and Linux have ssh available out of the box. No need for a separate package like you need on Windows.

Comment: TigerVNC worked for me on this. Vinagre, unfortunately, did not (it requires entering the username).

Comment: Would be helpful to disable not screen sharing, but only the VNC option

Comment: on OSX 10.13.6 ok

Comment: Warning: macos 10.14 and later only allows control if Screen Sharing is enabled through System Preferences.

Comment: Works on Mojave as well, despite the warning. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: Still works on Big Sur 11.3.1 !!!

Comment: Worked today on my mid-2011 Mac mini running High Sierra 10.13.6.  Word of warning, though - this enables Remove Management rather than Screen Sharing - and don't try to swap from one to the other through the remote GUI - oops :-)

Answer (score 45):

Here is a different way, that enables screen sharing access for all current users, instead of using a single VNC password:

```bsh
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart \
 -activate -configure -access -on \
 -configure -allowAccessFor -allUsers \
 -configure -restart -agent -privs -all
```

Disable it with this:

```bsh
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -deactivate -configure -access -off
```

This allows you to connect to the remote computer from a mac using the `share screen` button in Finder.

Reference: http://ss64.com/osx/kickstart.html

Comment: For posterity: if you do this, you can also connect via `/System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing.app`.

Comment: Note that you can (very) easily launch the Screen Sharing app using a Spotlight search

Comment: doesn't work for me on macOS Sierra 10.12

Comment: worked for me on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Got this response on macOS Mojave:
"Warning: macos 10.14 and later only allows control if Screen Sharing is enabled through System Preferences."

Comment: Latest edit has a type in first command in "Resouces" -> "Resources", and I cannot edit just that because I'd need to fix more stuff that doesn't need to be fixed

```bash
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart 
 -activate -configure -access -on 
 -configure -allowAccessFor -allUsers 
 -configure -restart -agent -privs -all
```

Comment: Not working for me on 10.15.7. Once this command is run, you can connect with Screen Sharing, but the screen is black. By contrast, turning it on with the System Preferences app, you don't get that issue.

Comment: Works on 14.2.1 -- you are brilliant!