# Change Screen Resolution for Mac Built-in VNC (Screen Sharing)

Tags: display, remote-desktop, resolution, screen-sharing

I am attempting to connect to a MacBook Pro from a Mac Pro with a 2560x1600 monitor using the built in screen sharing client.  I would like to be able have the connection fill the entire screen, but currently the best I can do is set the MacbookPro's resolution to 1680x1050 which fills about 2/3 of the 2560x1600 monitor.

Since the built in client is really a vnc server, I would like to be able to set the 'served' resolution to 2560x1600 instead of the native resolution of the MacBook Pro.  On a linux server this would be as simple as `$vncserver -geometry 2560x1600` and then connecting to the created server.  Is there a way to get the native mac vnc client to do this?

For what it is worth, I found the location of the client (on Sierra): 
`/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleVNCServer` but can't figure out what arguments it might take (if any)

[This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30238/how-to-enable-os-x-screen-sharing-vnc-through-ssh) seemed to use `ARDAgent` to activate and configure the VNC server but did not mention anything about setting the resolution for the server.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution in this article:[How to change Macbook Screen Resolution Manually](https://notebooks.com/2016/02/07/change-macbook-screen-resolution-manually/).

I used the DisableMonitor application.
https://notebooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/disablemonitor-resolution-menu-1024x754.png

Comment: Thank you for those references but is recommended that one also clearly writes down in her or his reply the steps suggested in those references as solutions in addition to the internet addresses. This is recommended because the addresses for the web pages referred to may change or the sites may be taken down in the future.

Comment: I don't think this let's you go above native resolution, which is the problem in question...